# How to make sure that not concat duplicated objects in array?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

Im learning `Reactive Programming` using `RxJs` and need some help to find the best operator for this situation. Im developing a `angular 4` app and have this method:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.returnUsers();
  }

  returnUsers() : void {
    this.userService.ListUsers(this.token)
        .subscribe(response => {
            this.token = response.token;
            this.users = this.users.concat(response.users);
        });
  }

  scrollDown() {
    this.returnUsers();
  }
```

The functionality is ok, *the problem is that if the user scroll too fast, the token that i send to the server is the same, so i concat duplicated objects*. I would like to know how is the best approach to deal with it. I tried with `.filter` operator, too concat just the not repeated objects but im still hitting the server.

Edit:
Im using the [angular2-infinite-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-infinite-scroll)

Comment: have you tried distinctUntilChanged?

Comment: I tried now, then i changed the throttle time (in the template of the scroll component that i use) to 10ms, and still making multiple repeated requests to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling the `scrollDown()` method on every scroll event?

If so then you're making a new subscription for every scroll event which is probably not what you want.
I think you'll need to use `Subject` instance and push a value on every scroll event. Then you can use `debounceTime(100)` to discard emission that arrive too quickly and also have a single subscription.

Something like this (obviously I didn't test this code but I hope you'll get the point).

```
private subject$ = new Subject();

constructor() {
    this.subject$
        .debounceTime(100)
        .concatMap(() => this.userService.ListUsers(this.token))
        .subscribe(response => {
            this.token = response.token;
            this.users = this.users.concat(response.users);
        });
    });
}

scrollDown() {
    this.subject$.next();
}
```

Comment: it worked martin, thanks. I just didnt get why i need to put `this.subject$.next();` in the constructor after the subscribe line to get the first results. Should calling the subscribe method on the constructor already do that?

Comment: @ggui `this.subject$.next();` is inside the `scrollDown()` method, not in the constructor